# itextSharp ColumnText only showing everyother foreach loop Phrase

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, itext

I have the following code in my controller using iTextSharp to show a list of hazards split over two columns if the list is too long for one.

How ever when I run it I only get every other hazard being displayed in the document.

int hazardsids has all 28 but only 14 are displayed and having checked the results it is only displaying hazards with an even number for the ID?

```
ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(cb);
ct.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_JUSTIFIED;

Paragraph hazardTitle = new Paragraph("Hazards", bold);
hazardTitle.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
doc.Add(hazardTitle);
//Get vertical position of hazardTitle
var pos = pdfWriter.GetVerticalPosition(false);
int[] hazardIds = db.RiskAssessmentHazards
                    .Where(x => x.RiskAssessmentId == raId)
                    .OrderBy(x => x.HazardId)
                    .Select(x => x.HazardId)                                   
                    .ToArray();
foreach (int HazardIds in hazardIds)
{
    ct.AddText(new Phrase("- " + db.Hazards.FirstOrDefault(x => x.HazardId == HazardIds).Name + "\n"));
}

float gutter = 15f;

float colwidth = (doc.Right - doc.Left - gutter) / 2;               

float[] left = { doc.Left , pos,
  doc.Left , doc.Bottom };

float[] right = { doc.Left + colwidth, doc.Top - 80f, 
    doc.Left + colwidth, doc.Bottom };

float[] left2 = { doc.Right - colwidth, pos,
    doc.Right - colwidth, doc.Bottom };

float[] right2 = {doc.Right, doc.Top - 80f,
    doc.Right, doc.Bottom };

int status = 0;
int i = 0;
//Checks the value of status to determine if there is more text
//If there is, status is 2, which is the value of NO_MORE_COLUMN
while (ColumnText.HasMoreText(status))
{
    if (i == 0)
    {
        //Writing the first column
        ct.SetColumns(left, right);
        i++;
    }
    else
    {
        //write the second column
        ct.SetColumns(left2, right2);
    }

    //Needs to be here to prevent app from hanging
    ct.YLine = pos;
    //Commit the content of the ColumnText to the document
    //ColumnText.Go() returns NO_MORE_TEXT (1) and/or NO_MORE_COLUMN (2)
    //In other words, it fills the column until it has either run out of column, or text, or both
    status = ct.Go();
}
```

Comment: We don't have your database. We cannot tell whether only every other hazard is filled. Thus, please provide a sample that is reproducible for people outside your organisation, and reproducible without extensive preparations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tried your sample code, simulating your database call with an array of hard-coded 'words', and could reproduce the same problem - only even numbered 'HazardIds' are written to the PDF. Only took a quick look, so not exactly sure whether the problem is where you're calling `Go()` or something else, but here's a simple working example that does what you're looking for:

```
Font font = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 20);
string word = "word word word word";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;
ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(cb);
ct.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_JUSTIFIED;

Paragraph hazardTitle = new Paragraph("Hazards", font);
hazardTitle.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;

var pos = writer.GetVerticalPosition(false) - 40;
float gutter = 15f;
float colwidth = (doc.Right - doc.Left - gutter) / 2;
float col0right = doc.Left + colwidth;
float col1left = col0right + gutter;
float col1right = col1left + colwidth;
float[][] COLUMNS = 
{
    new float[] { doc.Left, doc.Bottom, col0right, pos },
    new float[] { col1left, doc.Bottom, col1right, pos }
};

for (int i = 1; i <= 40; ++i )
{
    ct.AddText(new Phrase(string.Format(
        "- [{0}] {1}", 
        i, sb.Append(word).ToString()
    )));
    ct.AddText(Chunk.NEWLINE);
}

int status = 0;
int column = 0;
while (ColumnText.HasMoreText(status))
{
    ct.SetSimpleColumn(
        COLUMNS[column][0], COLUMNS[column][1],
        COLUMNS[column][2], COLUMNS[column][3]
    );
    status = ct.Go();
    column = Math.Abs(column - 1);
    if (column == 0)
    {
        doc.Add(hazardTitle);
        doc.NewPage();
    }
}
// add last title if first column still has space
if (column != 0)
{
    doc.Add(hazardTitle);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @kuujinbo thats fixed the issue, thanks for taking the time to make something of my incomplete post